# Creating a Picture Log with HTML index

Tags: html, image

I have a large hard drive full of photos/videos all organized into folders by events or years, which works for me. However, I want a way to just view them all in total just organized by date. Is there any way to easily code it into some sort of an HTML index that takes all the pictures without having to manually write the source to each picture. (Im not planning on hosting it or anything)

I assume this can't happen, so is there an easy way/program to grab all photos/videos from folders within folders and paste them all into one folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell us which OS you are using. I will show you the way under Windows10.

- open an explorer-window
- move to the root-directory of your photos/videos
- in the upper right there is a search-window.
- lets presume your videos have the format mp4. Enter *.mp4 and press [enter]
- you will get all videos including all videos in your sub-directorties in one plain list
- press [ctrl]-a (this will select all videos), [ctrl]-c (copy all videos) or [ctrl]-x (mark all for deletion), move to the new spot in your directory-structure and press [ctrl]-v (copies all selected videos to this spot). 
  **Alternatively** you can open a second explorer-window, move to the new spot and move all videos with your mouse from one window to the other. Please note that it may take some time for the OS to do the work if the amount of files is real big.
- repeat this for all video- and picture-formats.

That way you need no programming at all.
It can easily be done in linux too but I don't have the correct commands at hand at the moment. HTH.